# Write files through python in docker-compose container and exists in host using volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, fastapi, docker-volume

I am sorry first of all upon my awful language and I am still beginner in docker.

Basically I have volumes in my docker-compose.yml.

```
volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
  
      - traefik-public-certificates:/certificates
      
      - /home/gambar:/gambar/
```

I am using fastApi to create files

```
@app.get("/")
async def test():
   
    f = open("gambar/demofile2.txt", "x")
    f.write("Now the file has more content!")
    f.close()
    return RedirectResponse("https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ?t=42")
```

Here is what I have in Dockerfile

```
RUN mkdir gambar
```

The problem is when I was executing the request URI, it worked perfectly but the demofile2.txt cannot be found in host. Even I make a API URI in order to see if the files exist in container.

```
@app.get("/test")
async def tests():
    return {"dir":os.listdir(),"dalam_gambar":os.listdir("/gambar")}
```

The reponse:

```
{
   "dir":[
      "lib64",
      "dev",
      "bin",
      "srv",
      "opt",
      "run",
      "boot",
      "usr",
      "home",
      "sbin",
      "mnt",
      "etc",
      "proc",
      "tmp",
      "media",
      "sys",
      "root",
      "var",
      "lib",
      "gambar1",
      "gambar",
      "app",
      ".dockerenv",
      "chromedriver",
      "requirements.txt"
   ],
   "dalam_gambar":[
      "demofile2.txt"
   ]
}
```

Did I do it correct in order to get the files from container's gambar directory into host or specifically in /home/gambar?

If it was unclear, let me know.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. The lack of a leading slash on the file name would seem suspicious, but if you are running with the root directory as your working directory, it should not matter. Can you reduce this to a [mre]?

Comment: (i.e. the missing forward slash here: `f = open("gambar/demofile2.txt", "x")` will probably point to a different directory than what `os.listdir("/gambar")` points to.)